# PHP: Warning: include failed to open stream no such file or directory on Windows

Tags: php, include

I have an include statement in a PHP script running on xampp on Windows.  If I use a relative path :

```
include '../config/eventInfoConfig.php';
```

I get the error message:

> Warning: include(../config/eventInfoConfig.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

But if I use the absolute path I have no error:

```
include 'c:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/appTrials/myApp/config/eventInfoConfig.php';
```

How can I use a relative path in my include without causing an error?

Comment: What does `var_dump(get_include_path())` output?

Comment: string(42) ".;C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;"  But I think you have answered my question.  I need to include a path to my apache htdocs folder in the include_path parameter in my php.ini file.  That works!  Thanks very much for your help!!

Comment: I just ran into the exact same error for the exact same reason. Why the hell does it not try to resolve the path relative to the script's directory before resorting to include_path?!

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixing the `include_path()` to include the right path does the trick.

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 4):

I would make it dynamic so that you can also include this file in other files and still have it work properly.

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/eventInfoConfig.php');
```

Comment: I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the relative path into an absolute one. `include` is tricky. I always just keep a global constant, `BASE_PATH`, that contains the absolute path, and append the file I need to include.

Comment: include is not tricky, but relative path is tricky.

Comment: Include is indeed tricky. I have started a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507