# error come when set path to config.php

Tags: php, ckeditor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: Warning: include failed to open stream no such file or directory on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525423/php-warning-include-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory-on-windows)

My main folder is play. It contains config.php and login folder

login folder has a sub folder called `ckeditor` and it contains sub folder _samples. It has my php file selectnew.php

I want to include config.php to selectnew.php.

I have set path as follows:

```
include('play\config.php');
```

also I have tried

```
include('play/config.php');
```

but the following error is the result:

```
Warning: include(play/config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\wamp\www\play\logins\ckeditor\_samples\selectnew.php on line 7

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'play/config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in D:\wamp\www\play\logins\ckeditor\_samples\selectnew.php on line 7
```

my folders

```
play  folder
    --config.php
   logins folder
      ckeditor  folder
              _samples folder
           selectnew.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go 2 folders up from your current directory (assuming your _samples contains your selectnew.php)

```
include("../../config.php");
```

..or you can use this approach to traverse from root folder

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."config.php");
```

By the way you code doesn't work because you are using relative path to your current file directory. So basically, when you do include("play/config.php") the code will try to include this file

> play/ckeditor/_samples/play/config.php

which doesn't existed.

Comment: it work  well  thank you--  is it also work for Linux ? if doesn't work how it set

Answer (score 2):

Going by this path `D:\wamp\www\play\logins\ckeditor\_samples\selectnew.php`, you should use

```
include('../../config.php');
```

The `../` goes back a step. So if you go back two times, you'll be in the `play` folder.